# Power BI - Aurora RDS Postgres security

Tags: powerbi, amazon-rds, powerbi-desktop, amazon-aurora

I have a Aurora RDS PostgresSQL instance and I have enabled SSL on it.
Now I want to connect to this instance using Power BI, I have managed to connect to my instance over SSL using Power BI.
But it seems that it is not a easy task.
I will be sharing these details to some non technical team and I think they will find this quite difficult to set up.

My question is :

- What if I disable my forced enabled SSL over RDS ? ( to make the setup easy )
- What will be the security consequences to it ?
- What is the better approach to handle this situation ?
- How the communication will be done between Power BI and RDS , it will be over HTTP or HTTPS ?
- What types of attacks that can occur on my instance ?
- Any other situations should be taken care of ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is definitely too broad, but I'll try to summarize my take on your questions.

> What if I disable my forced enabled SSL over RDS ? ( to make the setup easy )
>   What will be the security consequences to it ?

If you plan on enabling public endpoints, or plan to have custom security groups that open up your DB endpoint outside of your VPC, then this is a bad idea. If you are not going to open up your firewall rules, then this is definitely an option, provided you accept the risk that the weakest link to this security model is guarding an attacker from getting access to your VPC. If an attacker can ssh into one of your client EC2 nodes, consider the data to be compromised as he can always do man in the middle at that point.

> What is the better approach to handle this situation ?

Disabling security practices to make setup easier is in general a anti-pattern. You setup your infrastructure just a handful of times, as opposed to interacting with it. There have been even bigger reasons to consider disabling TLS. For eg: a lot of the JDBC drivers don't really support TLS certificates that have multiple endpoints (via SAN) in the cert. Even in those cases, the right thing to do in those cases is to contribute to the client code and make it support whats missing.

> How the communication will be done between Power BI and RDS , it will be over HTTP or HTTPS ?

Not sure I understand this one. If you enable SSL, then you have the option of talking both raw TCP as well as SSL. If you disable un-encrypted connections, you can only talk SSL. And if you don't do anything, then you're talking raw TCP.

> What types of attacks that can occur on my instance ?

1. If your instance is publicly accessible - You're open for DDos. You
   can't do much to prevent that. (at least, I'm not aware of anything
   you can do to your db clusters to handle that)
2. If you don't have SSL enabled, then an attacker can pretend to be the database and steal your creds/queries. If public endpoints are not enabled, this attack is slightly more unlikely given that the attacker has to penetrate the VPC first.
3. If you do have SSL enabled, but you talk over raw TCP (ie SSL is not enforced), then you are vulnerable to MITM.
4. If you have SSL enabled, but you don't do endpoint validation, then you are again vulnerable to MITM.

> Any other situations should be taken care of ?

Too broad. Even if you enable SSL, you could be vulnerable if you don't store your secrets (creds) in a guarded manner. You may want to stop creating normal DB users in favor of IAM users. It does not add security, but it gives you more manageability and incidence response. You can also force all your applications to use temporary credentials everywhere, as opposed to actually using your IAM credentials, thereby reducing the scope of compromised credentials.

In general, a lot of your questions are generic security practices and not specific to RDS or databases at all. Hope this helps.